# When it is preferable to have a multi-language platform and when is not?

Tags: usability, language, internationalisation, multi-language

In a world where English became the second language for most people or at least for the users that buy on international platforms, multi-language websites/ apps are still the best choice for a good UX? I know having the platform in the native language of a user is the best choice, but this comes with multiple challenges, and also it is hard to cover a large number of languages.
What do you think, when it is recommended to have the platform in English/ the most used language for the website/app users and when it is better to have a multi-language platform?

Answer (score 2):

#### When users' experience is localized

If your users are interacting with content across continents, it's *less* important to translate than when they are interacting and consuming content within their locale. For instance, if you are delivering news about Japan in Japan, you would not expect it to be in English. However, it's less likely consumers of international news would expect it to be in their native language.

#### When you are trying to maximize sales

If providing translated content gives a boost to sales that outweighs the cost to translate, then it makes perfect financial sense to do so.

#### SEO

Your site will place higher in search rankings in international versions of the search engines.

#### Branding

By having an international platform, the brand becomes multinational and appears larger and more successful.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Maybe the question in the title doesn't summarise exactly the issue... I wrote in the description more. I think the question is multi-language websites/ apps are the best choice for a good UX, even this comes with multiple challenges, and also it is hard to cover a large number of languages?

Comment: This question came from personal experience, I have for my portfolio multiple languages available and I'm not sure this offers a plus for the website...